# Checkout and build project using Jenkins

Tags: maven, svn, jenkins, pom.xml

I have successfully configured the `SVN repository url` in `Jenkins` and now i want to build that project through Jenkins, but i want some clarification as i am new to Jenkins.

1. Can i download the code using `Jenkins` to my local repository without installing any Subversion software?
2. If yes, please enlighten me.. If No, may i know the reason or any alternative..
3. Based on 2 step, i want to build the project(Maven) using Jenkins.. for that i have specified the `Root POM` option in build step... when i am using the `SVN URL` to located the `POM.xml`, it is displaying an error in `Jenkins` as `No such file: ‘http://<POM.xml path>`

Please advise, thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try it? run your job only with SCM configured on a slave without a subversion client and tell us your findings.

Comment: Regarding the root pom - you've already checked out your repository, use the local file in your workspace: $WORKSPACE/Path/To/pom.xml

Comment: When i am opting for `Poll SCM`, there is option of `Schedule` with a TextArea. Can you please advise on schedule part as i am new with Poll SCM?

Comment: There is a question mark on the right with further explanation, but in general : */2 * * * * => every 2 minutes - this is the common use.

Answer (score 1):

- Build a job with only SCM configured on a machine with no client installed and see what happens. it'll answer your question
- Regarding the root pom - you've already checked out your repository, use the local file in your workspace: $WORKSPACE/Path/To/pom.xml
- For poll SCM scheduler you can use:

MINUTE HOUR DOM MONTH DOW

```
MINUTE  Minutes within the hour (0–59)
HOUR    The hour of the day (0–23)
DOM The day of the month (1–31)
MONTH   The month (1–12)
DOW The day of the week (0–7) where 0 and 7 are Sunday.
```

Example:

*/2 * * * * will run every 2 minutes.